# Reshaping a column into rows, based on equality of corresponding column

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to reshape a dataframe in which subsequent cells that have the equal corresponding values on another column should be transitioned into a new dataframe or matrix with them in the same row, but in different cells.

As an example for the mechanism, the dataframe `df`

```
df <- data.frame(PATID=c(1,2,2,3,3,3), SUB = c("5A", "2A", "2B", "1A", "2A", "2Y"))

PATID   SUB 
    1    5A 
    2    2A 
    2    2B 
    3    1A 
    3    2A 
    3    2Y
```

should be transformed into

```
5A 
2A 2B
1A 2A 2Y
```

With in this case three rows (= # of unique values in `df$PATID`) and three columns but this should be scalable.

After searching, I have not found any equivalent question.

Comment: Search "reshape long to wide"

Comment: Thanks; I checked it but I miss a `timevar` here, right? (which basically would be the # of observations per PATID)